# Destroy gameObject oncomplete

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itween

I am using this script to destroy a gameObject oncomplete, but it doesn't work.

```
void Jump()
{
    if (currentCube.transform.position.y == 0f) 
    {
        iTween.MoveTo (currentCube, iTween.Hash ("y", currentCube.transform.position.y - 15f, "time", 0.8f, "oncomplete", "DestroyOnComplete", "oncompletetarget", currentCube, "easeType", "easeInCubic", "loopType", "none", "delay", 0));
    }
}

public void DestroyOnComplete()
{   
    Destroy (currentCube);
    Debug.Log ("Destroyed " + currentCube);
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Define `doesn't work`.

Comment: you got the debug line?

Comment: Well it doesn't do anything, no error, no debug. The currentcube does fall down and stops at -15.

Comment: You may want to check if this is true: `if (currentCube.transform.position.y == 0f)` by putting `Debug.Log` inside it. By the way, it's not a good idea to compare float like that. That may never be true.

Comment: I know what you mean. In this game i've never seen it randomly go 0.9999999 or something like that, but I will use Mathf.Approximately to make it sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see your script is not attached to `currentCube` and you're trying to invoke `DestroyOnCompleted` on `currentCube`. Try something like this :

```
iTween.MoveTo (
    currentCube,
    iTween.Hash (
        "y",
        currentCube.transform.position.y - 15f,
        "time",
        0.8f,
        "oncomplete",
        "DestroyOnComplete",
        "oncompletetarget",
        gameObject, // here you had `currentCube`, you can even try with `this` instead
        "easeType",
        "easeInCubic",
        "loopType",
        "none",
        "delay",
        0
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works :) I thought the oncompletetarget had to be the cube which should be destroyed. I changed it so it destroys pastCube, which is the same as currentCube AFTER a jump. So that the cube I am past will be destroyed and not the cube i'm standing on :)